# Android Application to setup another app

Tags: android, configuration, mobile-website

I want to know that, Can we create an app on Android in which we can configure the settings of another application. I want to have an app to behave like a server in which the changes are done and the settings are loaded in the main application. Want to know that if its possible
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Idea just come into my mind after reading your question, try it your self but it is 100% going to work.

Create an application that stores the configuration data into SharedPreference. Make this SharedPreference as public so that you can easily read from your another application.

Now in your another application you can use this SharedPreference's data as configurations.

Comment: Oh great, nice workflow, will definitely try this today. thanks Raynold

Comment: Additionally i want know that, can i some how create a web app which can be accessed from any ip address or web address so we can be independent of the device on which that configuration application is installed ?

Comment: @CodeAddiction, sorry i didnt get you.